# UIView contents image

Tags: objective-c, uiview, calayer

I want get texture or image from UIVIew like screenshot. But without create CGContext, and draw UIView on this context. If this view display on screen, i think it contains this texture somewhere inside. How can I get this texture/image from UIView? How can I catch moment redraw this texture(E.g. change highliten button inside view)?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a texture stored for a rendered UIView. There will be a framebuffer under the hood somewhere but I don't think you can get at that.

Like you said, you can render a view's layer to a CGContext. This is easily done and I believe it's the only way of achieving what you want. What are your reasons for avoiding this approach? Perhaps you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: I use GPUImage filters, and I want apply them to UIView. How can I catch moment redraw contents?

Comment: Subclass UIView, override drawRect: call [super drawRect] then get the current graphics context. GPUImage has examples of how to input a graphics context or an image created from a graphics context into a filter and get the output - The filtering part may have be done in a queue running on another thread as to allow drawRect to return asap.

Comment: I can't catch moment when button state highlighted changed. Or activity indicator view redrawed.